# Java Connecting Two classes with printwriter object

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor, printwriter

I am having a lot of troubles here. I need to match the code with the following `Driver class` along with `Decimal class`,`Menu class`,`Binary class` and `Hexadecimal class`. As you can see below `Driver class`, I wrote `Decimal class`. I know it is poorly made but the biggest problem I have is I have no idea how to send all output to csis.txt by using `printwriter` object and other methods. An exclamation mark in Eclipse for `Decimal dec = new Decimal(pw);` indicates, the value of the local variable is not used. Also, how do I use `Decimal.pw` in `Decimal class`?

Here is a `Driver's class` I need to use.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
        int choice;
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("csis.txt"));
        Decimal dec = new Decimal(pw);
        Binary bin = new Binary(pw);
        Hexadecimal hex = new Hexadecimal(pw);
        Menu menu = new Menu(pw);

        do {
            menu.display();
            choice = menu.getSelection();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: dec.decToBin(); break;
                case 2: dec.decToHex(); break;
                case 3: bin.binToDec(); break;
                case 4: bin.binToHex(); break;
                case 5: hex.hexToDec(); break;
                case 6: hex.hexToBin(); break;
            }
        }while (choice != 7);
        pw.print("Sends to output file.");
        pw.println("Sends to output file with linefeed.");
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Here is a `Decimal class`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Decimal{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inDec;  
    int num;
    int rem;//remainder

    private PrintWriter pw;
    public Decimal(PrintWriter pw) {
        this.pw = pw;
    }

    //Allows user to type in a positive decimal number
    public void inputDec(){
        System.out.println("Enter a positive decimal number. I will convert into a binary number.");
        inDec = kb.nextInt();
        num = inDec;
    }

    //converts decimal into binary
    public void decToBin(){
        if (num < 0){
            System.out.println("Error. You should put a positive decimal number.");
        }
        else if (num == 0){
            System.out.println("0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000");
        }
        else{
        int binary[] = new int[32];
        for(int j=0; num>0; j++){
            binary[j] = num%2;
            num = num/2;
        } 
        for(int j=31; j>=0; j--){
            System.out.print(binary[j]);
                if(j%4==0)
                    System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }

    //Allows user to type in a positive decimal number
    public void inputHex(){
        System.out.println("Enter a positive decimal number. I will convert into a hexadecimal number.");
        inDec = kb.nextInt();
        num = inDec;
    }

    //converts decimal into hexadecimal
    public void decToHex(){
         String str=""; 
         char hex[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

         while(num>0)
         {
           rem=num%16; 
           str=hex[rem]+str; 
           num=num/16;
         }
         System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about checking how `PrintWriter` is used in `Binary`? What should be it's purpose in `Decimal`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It should print out all kinds of outputs or results in csis.txt if this is what you are asking.

Comment: Here's a hint, `System.out` is kind of a `PrintWriter` writing to stdout.

Comment: I don't catch it... Could you explain it more specific please?